# Primeng Table Responsive layout stack/scroll not working

Tags: angular, responsive, primeng

I am using PrimeNG in my Angular project. I am trying to make the table elements show in "stack" mode when responsive, which should be a simple thing according to the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/responsive).

Yet it does not work in my code, the rows don't get stacked for small screen sizes:

[image: example image]

Here is my `component.html`:

```html
<div class="card">
  <p-table responsiveLayout="stack" [value]="questions">
    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
      <h5 class="p-m-0">Trial Table</h5>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr>
        <th pSortableColumn="main">Question <p-sortIcon field="main"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="content">Content <p-sortIcon field="content"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="timeToRead">Time To Read <p-sortIcon field="timeToRead"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="timeToRecord">Time To Record <p-sortIcon field="timeToRecord"></p-sortIcon></th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-question let-columns="columns">
      <tr>
        <td><span class="p-column-title">Question</span>{{question.main}}</td>
        <td><span class="p-column-title">Content</span>{{question.content}}</td>
        <td><span class="p-column-title">Time To Read</span>{{question.timeToRead}}</td>
        <td><span class="p-column-title">Time To Record</span>{{question.timeToRecord}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
```

Here is a light version of my `component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questions',
  templateUrl: './questions.component.html',
})
export class QuestionsComponent {
  questions = [{ main: 'valueA', content: 'valueB', timeToRead: 'valueC', timeToRecord: 'valueD' }];
}
```

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/video.js": "^7.3.19",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "color": "^3.1.3",
    "firebase": "^8.6.7",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^5.0.0",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^12.0.0-rc.1",
    "reading-time": "^1.3.0",
    "recordrtc": "^5.6.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "swiper": "^6.7.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "video.js": "^7.12.3",
    "videojs-record": "^4.5.0",
    "webrtc-adapter": "^8.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.15",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to stack fine by default: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aacydq. I'm wondering if there's perhaps some responsive breakpoint customization in your project? The stacking should happen at 960px by default unless Table.breakpoint is overriden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a property **responsive** which you can bind to.
If you add `[responsive]="true"` to your `p-table` component, it should work correctly.

Comment: I've been stuck on this for a few days, and this is what fixed it for me. I am not sure if it is a version-related variation, since it seems that in certain versions it would work without the `[responsive]="true"` attribute  (and also the primeng documentation example didn't include the `[responsive]="true"` part). Thank you.

Comment: Actually, this attribute doesn't make your table to be a fully responsive table, it really needs extra effort. primeNg tables are sucks! responsiveness-wise

Answer (score 5):

since PrimeNg version 12.1.0 you can use responsiveLayout="stack", prior to that there is the input [responsive]="true"

Answer (score 0):

using primeNg version 17.4.0 with this values:

<p-table [scrollable]="true" responsiveLayout="stack">
...

and doesn't working, only appears the stack layout at it's breakpoint if scrollable is false... some of primeng components are deceptioning me, i'm overwritting a lot of their css classes to achieve what a i want (and yes, i have tried to use documentation before, some cases work, some not).